# How to assign Azure Cosmos DB access policy in keyvault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I want cosmos db to access the key from the key vault for encryption. I am not able to add an access policy for Cosmos in Keyvault. So I added the below code.

```
module "cosmosdb_app_access_policy" {
  source = "git::ssh://git@blabla/keyvault-access-policy.git"

  key_vault_id = module.keyvault.id
  tenant_id    = var.tenant_id
  object_id    = "060998cb-5ff8-48d6-b528-10eaaeb95e1d" # Azure CosmosDB App Object ID

  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Update"]
}
```

`060998cb-5ff8-48d6-b528-10eaaeb95e1d` value is currently hardcoded. I want to get it from Terraform.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to assign the Azure cosmos DB Access policy in keyvault and I was successfully passed the object ID created from the terraform.

Here I try to create Cosmos DB Account with configuration as mentioned below.

**configuration for Cosmos_db**

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  resource_group_name = "demovk-rg"
  location            = "East US"
  name                = "demovk-resource"
}



resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example" {
  name                  = "demovkwwvk-resource"
  location              = "East US"
  resource_group_name   = "demovk-rg"
  default_identity_type = join("=", ["UserAssignedIdentity", azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id])
  offer_type            = "Standard"
  kind                  = "MongoDB"

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Strong"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = "eastus"
    failover_priority = 0
  }

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id]
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example]
}

output "Object_id" {
    value   = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.identity[0].principal_id
}
```

with this configuration we will be able to configure the cosmos dB account auto enabled `SystemUserIdentity`  **Object_ID**.

we can see the value as an **output** here.

**Output:**

[image]

&
[image]

In the next step we need to provision the vault and access policy.

**main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "vkvkvkkeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "demovk-rg"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example-principal" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.identity[0].principal_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "List",
    "Encrypt",
    "Decrypt",
  ]
  depends_on = [azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example]
}
```

This will access the existing key vault and try providing the access policy as per the requirement.

**Output:**

[image]

&

[image]

By this configuration we can call the object ID using terraform we need not to hard code it and we also can create a access policy for cosmos dB.

Comment: The problem is with key assigning for CMK. When I assign CMK first, it does not have a policy to access the key and if I create cosmos DB first then can't assign the key later (the key can be assigned at creation)

Comment: Creating the key first and assigning it to CMK will result in cycle_error. However, making the Cosmosdb provisioned first and trying to access the key later is also tricky because encryption_config doesn't support the module.